# Unable to call script function from command line

Tags: powershell

I am trying to call a function in a PowerShell script in the same directory. However, when I call it, I get this error:

> The term 'functionName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script...

Any idea why this occurs? I also tried dot loading the script first like this before calling the function:

```
.\Script.psm1
```

Comment: PSM1? Is your function in a module? Do you need to run `Import-Module` first?

Comment: Thanks, importing the module worked.

Answer (score 2):

`.\Script.psm1` would run the script ([script module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324.aspx), actually) in a child context. To be able to use functions from it in the current context you need to run/load it in the current context. That can be done via [dot-sourcing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) for regular scripts, or via [`Import-Module`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849725.aspx) (for modules).